# Is there a way to Get all variable names in a class programatically using APEX?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, java

If i have a class as shown below-

```
 public class ClassName{
        String field1{get;set;}
        String field2{get;set;} 
 }
```

Is there a way to get the fieldname of the above class in apex code.
I need to get **field1** and **field2** programmatically. 
 I found it is possible in java as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2126722)
Is there something equivalent in salesforce?

Comment: No. You could add your vote to this 5 year old idea here [Apex Reflection](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVaAAK).

Comment: @Akash https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090fnIAA once refer this link

Comment: @Sathya Your link relates to the special case of SObjects - really information about the database schema and also some information used by the UI - rather than the general ability to find out about the fields etc of an ordinary Apex class.

Comment: @satya Ya i am asking about normal apex class not the Objects

Comment: @KeithC Thanks for the reply , hope they add this feature in the upcoming release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Keith C replied - it's not possible to get such information in apex but as a workaround you can use Tooling API or implement the following steps: 1. instantiate object 2. serialize to JSON 3. take all fields via JSON parser.